# <unknown error> while fetching data from MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data, using Stored Procedure from **mysql** workbench but I get this error

`SQLSTATE[45000]: <<Unknown error>>: 1644 175`

What is the reason for such error, and how can I correct it?

Query (Inside stored procedure) -

```
SELECT User_Id,
       Login_Id,
       User_Name,
       User_Lname,
       (SELECT Dist_Name from district_mstr where Dist_Code = District) AS District
from users 
WHERE User_Id != 'uoo1' 
  and District = 'ny';
```

Removing this line  `and District = 'ny'` gives me all the result

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure?

Comment: There may be so many things. How could someone identify and answer your query with little information provided by you? Make the job easy for the audience by providing as much details as you can.

Comment: @yusufhayırsever I updated my query

Comment: @harry I updated my query